# Md5 wasn't be changed?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, md5, rar

I have 3 rar files ( all is same md5) I use this code to change Md5:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
 set /A Counter=0


FOR %%1 in (*.rar) do (

        set /A Counter= !Counter! + 1
                COPY  %%1+!Counter!
                echo !Counter!

)

pause
```

When I run .bat file, it shows 3 row with value: 1, 2, 3 but when I check md5 of 3 rar files, they is same although they were changed. Why ? What wrong I did? Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

`copy` works with files, not variables.

The method you used does add an end of file Hex 1A character onto the file - and my MD5 calculator shows different MD5 figures.

Comment: I have no idea, what `copy file.ext+1` should do, but every time I do it, the file gets one byte bigger.

Comment: @Stephan It is adding end of file markers, which are stripped by many programs.

Comment: ah - thank you. Then the md5-calculation-program oviously is one of those.

Comment: @Stephan The curious thing is that as RAR files are binary in nature and a binary file can contain hex 1A characters - and the MD5 generation does include them. I tested the MD5 hash of two files which differed by just the number of hex 1A at the end of the file (using the method above) and the two MD5 were different.